# lightning:datatable boolean type inline editing

Tags: lightning-datatable

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation

As per the above document, `lightning:datatable` does support `boolean` type.

[image]

But, it didn't say anything whether `boolean` type supports inline editing. I did one POC but it seems it is not supporting `inline editing`.
[image]

Is there any workaround to show the `checkbox` while doing `inline editing` for a `boolean` field?

Comment: It does support inline editing for boolean fields. You need to set editable attribute of boolean column to true. Refer **Working with Inline Editing** section https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation on this link.  It clearly says that inline editing is not supported for Date and Location fields. So It will support editing for boolean fields.

Comment: @AshishSharma : Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the boolean column supports inline editing, but what surprised me when I double clicked any checkbox you will see a long open text and there is no way you can check/uncheck. (Please see the image I posted).

My question is if I am missing something to see the checkbox to set the value?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It was coming due to the CSS. I have modified the existing CSS to hide some other checkbox and that was affecting this boolean column checkbox.

Thanks, guys for your help.